# How do I create a self referential association (self join) in a single class using ActiveRecord in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, self-join, self-reference

I am trying to create a self join table that represents a list of customers who can refer each other (perhaps to a product or a program). I am trying to limit my model to just one class, "Customer".

**TL;DR** available at bottom.

The schema is:

```
  create_table "customers", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "referring_customer_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "customers", ["referring_customer_id"], name: "index_customers_on_referring_customer_id"
```

My model is:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :referrals, class_name: "Customer", foreign_key: "referring_customer_id", conditions: {:referring_customer_id => :id}
  belongs_to :referring_customer, class_name: "Customer", foreign_key: "referring_customer_id"
end
```

I have no problem accessing a customer's referring_customer:

```
@customer.referring_customer.name
```

... returns the name of the customer that referred @customer.

However, I keep getting an empty array when accessing referrals:

```
@customer.referrals
```

... returns [].

I ran binding.pry to see what SQL was being run, given a customer who has a "referer" and *should* have several referrals. This is the SQL being executed.

```
      Customer Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers"
WHERE "customers"."id" = ? ORDER BY "customers"."id"
ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]

      Customer Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "customers"
WHERE "customers"."referring_customer_id" = ? AND
"customers"."referring_customer_id" = 'id' LIMIT 1 
[["referring_customer_id", 3]]
```

I'm a bit lost and am unsure where my problem lies. I don't think my query is correct -- @customer.referrals should return an array of all the referrals, which are the customers who have @customer.id as their referring_customer_id.

**TL;DR** Are self joins possible using only one class? If so, how do I set up my conditions and foreign keys so that my queries get me the correct data for the has_many relationship?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This association definition

```
has_many :referrals, class_name: "Customer", foreign_key: "referring_customer_id", conditions: {:referring_customer_id => :id}
```

isn't quite right.  There's no need to define the conditions clause - that's the whole point of the has_many.  It should be:

```
has_many :referrals, class_name: "Customer", foreign_key: "referring_customer_id"
```

which will use the referring_customer_id column on the customers table.

Comment: I noticed that when I took out the conditions,
1) it worked! Thanks!, and
2) the sql statement that checked for existence of referrals lost the query `AND "customers"."referring_customer_id" = 'id'` . I assume these were the `:conditions`. Why didn't this work though? I thought it was just restricting customers with referring_customer_id equal to the id of the customer.

Comment: The conditions as you wrote them were actually restricting the referring_customer_id to equal the string constant 'id'.  That what your SQL said as well if you read it carefully.  Please accept my answer if it was helpful - thanks!

Comment: Ahhh! I wish I checked this in the last hour. Just figured it out as well, and in fact, `conditions: "referring_customer_id = id"` checks for equivalence of the two integers whereas `conditions: {:referring_customer_id => :id}` fired a SQL statement that checked if the referring_customer_id equals the string 'id'. Thanks for your help Peter!